# Does Java's Arrays.asList() violate OOP?

Tags: java, arrays, oop, language-design, static-methods

In Java, I wanted to convert an array to a list. Given that Java is an OOP language I expected to do something like:

```
int[] myArray = { 1, 2, 3 };               // non-working code
List myList = myArray.toList();
```

but was surprised when I found the `array` object doesn't have a toList method and the correct way to do what I wanted was:

```
int[] myArray = { 1, 2, 3 };               // working Java code
List myList = Arrays.asList(myArray);
```

At first I wondered if an `int[]` was not considered an object but I was able to call methods such as `clone()` on it, so I am sure it is an object.

*Why did the designers of Java use the second approach (static method inconsistent with OOP) versus the first approach (opperate on an object consistent with OOP principles)?*

I've noticed C++ does stuff like the second approach too which I have assumed was baggage left over from C. But in C#, there is a `ToList()` method.

*Is the `Arrays.asList()` just a hold out on the evolutionary march towards OOP or was there some underlying theory to do it this way?*

Comment: It doesn't "break OOP", it's just poorly designed.

Comment: Humm. I would argue that poorly designed in an OOP language means it breaks OOP. So you would agree this is a poor design?

Comment: I thought that's what I said. But I disagree with your argument.

Comment: We don't know why the Java designers did what they did. You would have to ask *them.* All you will get here is more or less informed opinion and guesswork. And 'inconsistent with OOP' is subjective anyway in the absence of a universally accepted definition. Some proponents will probably just deny Java is an OOP language at all for example. Not me, I just find the entire debate quite pointless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arrays (`int[]`, `Foo[]`) were present in Java from the first version (JDK1.0). There was very little support for data structures - you had to do it all yourself. `List` and `ArrayList` and `Arrays` were introduced in V1.2 (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/ocs/api/java/util/List.html ). It's possible that when that occurred it wasn't possible to change the language or that it was too complex at the time.

I was a close observer of the early days of Java (through Sun contacts). I remember that Java 1.0 was fairly basic and the graphics (AWT 1.02) was written at the last moment. In my recollection Java was designed as OO but had initially limited scope (It was hyped as a new animation language, but Java AWT 1.02 was very limiting). There are artefacts from that period still resident in the spec.

The massive contribution of Java at that time was WriteOnceRunAnywhere (WORA) (initially WriteOnceDebugEverywhere!) and I suspect that that was the prime consideration in early developers and maintainers. Java was informed by C++ and carried some of the constructs (e.g. int, double as primitives - autoboxing came later as a kludge). C# was able to start from Java (rather than C++) and is in some ways a revision of how Java should be. All languages start with some baggage and each new one gets rid of some.

Comment: This seems to confirm what I suspected. They started off on the wrong foot and weren't able to recover. I don't see why they couldn't have added a `toArray()` method and just have its implementation return Arrays.asList(). Maybe to avoid multiple ways of doing the same thing???

Comment: Is there any mechanism via which Java could have an array's `ToList()` method return a proper generic type, given that `String[].ToList()` should yield a `ArrayList<String>`, but `int[].ToList()` would have to yield an `ArrayList<Integer>` if it worked at all?

Answer (score 3):

An int[] is an object.

However, nothing about OOP requires an object to provide all the factory methods that accept it as an argument.

Answer (score 3):

arrays don't have all sorts of method you might expect them to have and the methods it does have are inherited from Object and are generally useless.

```
int[] array = { 1, 2, 3 };
int[] array2 = { 1, 2, 3 };
System.out.println(array.equals(array2)); // prints false
System.out.println(array.hashCode() == array2.hashCode()); // prints false
System.out.println(array.toString()); // prints something like [I@a2634feg
```

I have tried to get Sun/Oracle to fix this but the rumour I got back was that to fix it properly would be very complicated.

Comment: So to answer the question, the way Java approaches this _does_ violate OOP?

Answer (score 1):

The conversion methods are not where you would expect them to be. And there is no real technical reason. If you look at Scala (which uses the same VM, and the bytecode is compatible):

```
object ArrayListDemo {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val list = args.toList
    val array = list.toArray

    println("= List =")
    println(list)
    println(list.mkString(", "))
    println(list.size)
    println(list.length)

    println("= Array =")
    println(array)
    println(array.mkString(", "))
    println(array.size)
    println(array.length)
  }
}
```

this will give you this result (if called with two arguments `Hello` and `world`):

> = List =
>   List(Hello, world)
>   Hello, world
>   2
>   2
>   = Array =
>   [Ljava.lang.String;@15663a2
>   Hello, world
>   2
>   2

You can see that it's really a "JVM array", with additional methods.
And all collections types (rich and primitive) have the conversion methods.

So, yes, it doesn't feel like OOP - it feels "imperative".